# Java Transliteration / replacing special characters to match ISO 8859-1 standard (LATIN-1)

Tags: java, transliteration

I have to replace special characters with standard LATIN-1 characters. I have spend very long time to search possible solutions of that. For now I have code (using ICU4J library) like that:

```java
import com.ibm.icu.text.Transliterator;


public class ApiUtils {
    private static final Transliterator transliterator = Transliterator.getInstance("Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII;  [[:P:]] Remove; NFKD;");

    public static String replaceSpecialCharacters(String text) {
        if (text == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return transliterator.transliterate(text);
    }
}
```

It works pretty well, for e.g.:

```
'бвгджзклмнпрстфхцчшщЬ' | 'bvgdzzklmnprstfhccss'
'ÀÂÇÉÔÛ'                | 'AACEOU'
```

but it misses some special characters like for e.g. ə, c, Ҝ, ҝ, ,Ө, ө, Ү, ү, Ҹ,ҹ. I can make a dictionary of characters like that, but I'm looking for universal solution. Do you know any good java library or possible solution of this?

Comment: There can't be a universal solution because any solution is subjective. You need to make the choices that are appropriate for your requirement. I am working on something similar.

Comment: it's true, I am aware that there can always be some characters, but I would like to replace as many of them as possible without manually supplementing the dictionary with additional characters.

Comment: Well some library might exist, but you might well have to end up rewriting it after it did something unexpected. 'ə' btw, despite being called  "LATIN SMALL LETTER SCHWA" is not really a letter at all, but a phonetic *symbol*. I can't really see any place for it in (real) letter substitutions